# Are there other legal/recognized Roulette variations than just the standard European and American?

Tags: casino

Currently, I know there are two main variations of the Casino Roulette layouts, the European (with a Single Zero "0") and the American (with Zero "0" and Double Zero "00"). Roulettes each with their characteristic sequence of numbers, and with their boards with numbers arranged in reading order:

[image]

I am not at all sure, but in the past I remember to have played in a Casino, with the double zero layout memorized, just to realize they had a different double zero layout.

Question is: Is there any other "legal" or recognized layout around there? Or the strongest possibility is I was a bit too drunk that night?

Comment: Do you remember what country the casino was in?

Answer (score 1):

A google image search will find the various different layouts including a triple zero layout.

[image: double zero adjacent]

This wheel was 0 and 00 adjacent.  the [page I found it on](https://www.roulettephysics.com/roulette-wheel-secrets/)  Says it in a casino in Australia.

If you search for 'triple zero roulette'  You will find many images of that layout as well and casinos that use them.